# reference to parent in foreach loop not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

We have an array of `questions`. Each question has an array of `answer`. Each answer has a `text` and `value`. Each `question` has the property `selectedAnswer` which preserves the selected answer's `value`.

**Implementation:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach : {data: questions}">

<p data-bind="text: desc"></p>
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: answers}">
  <div>
    <span>Working:</span>   
        <label data-bind="text: answer"></label>
        <input name="something" type="radio" data-bind="checked: model.selectedAnswer, value: value"></input>
    <span>...Not working--></span>
        <label data-bind="text: answer"></label>
        <input name="something" type="radio" data-bind="checked: $parent.selectedAnswer, value: value"></input>
  </div>
</div>

</div>

The selected answer is:
<span data-bind="text: model.selectedAnswer">
</span>
```

And here is the related `JavaScript`:

```
 model = {
    selectedAnswer: ko.observable(),
    questions: ko.observableArray()
  };

var q1 = {
  desc: 'Do you like JS?',
  answers: [
    {answer:'Yes', value:'Yaaay'},
    {answer:'No', value:'Nope'}
  ]
};

model.questions.push(q1);

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

**The problem:**
If I reference `selectedAnswer` by `model.selectedAnswer` it works fine. If I reference it by `$parent.selectedAnswer` it doesn't work. What am I missing?

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/votsevfd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that context, `$parent` refers to the question object, not the model itself.  You'll have to reference the grandparent (parent of the parent) to have access to the `model` members.

You can access them through the `$parents` context property. It's just an array of the parent objects relative to the current context. `$parents[0]` corresponds to the parent object (same as `$parent`). The grandparent is `$parents[1]`.

```
<input name="something"
       type="radio"
       data-bind="checked: $parents[1].selectedAnswer, value: value">
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/votsevfd/3/)